# How to interpret $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N^{d}} \frac{1}{n^{p}};$ and when it is converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

I know that: $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \frac{1 }{n^{p}}$ converges if $p>1$ and diverges if $p\leq 1$

> **My Question is**: What is an analogue  this in  more than one variable (say $d$)? Does it make sense to talk of $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N^{d}} \frac{1 }{n^{p}}$? (How I should interpretative  $\frac{1}{n^{p}}$ if $n\in \mathbb N^{d}$, I mean: is there any standard meaning..., etc...) After giving this meaning, what about its convergence?

Comment: It doesn't make sense

Comment: I guess for $2$ variables we could look at $\sum_m\sum_n \frac{1}{(mn)^p}$ or $\sum_m\sum_n \frac{1}{m^pn^q}$.  Or else look at $\sum_m\sum_n \frac{1}{||(m,n)||^p}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas; thanks: If I  consider $\sum_{(m,n)\in \mathbb N^{2}} \frac{1}{n^{p}m^{q}}$,and if one of them $p$ or $q$ is  1, what we can say; is it diverges? thanks

Comment: Yes if $p=1$ then the double sum diverges for any $q$.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is very natural to consider summing across integer points of a lattice as the multidimensional analogue. So for instance, you might consider
$$ \sum_{\vec n \in \mathbb{N}^d} \frac{1}{\lvert \vec n \rvert^p}$$
where $\lvert \vec n \rvert$ is the length of the vector $\vec n$. This agrees with the normal sum when $d = 1$.

And in general, it's not so hard to show that this converges for $p > d$.

Alternately, it might be natural to consider
$$ \sum_{n_i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n_1^{p_1} n_2^{p_2} \cdots n_k^{p_k}}$$

as each of the $p_i$ vary. This will converge for $p_i > 1$.

Comment: thanks, and  in the last expression of your series: I guess: the series diverges if one of the $p_{i}\leq$. Is it correct? KIndly advice me; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the question to make sense you can replace $n^p$ with $||(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_d)||^p$, where $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm of the vector. The number of $d$-dimensional vectors of norm in an interval of the form $[M,M+1]$ is well approximated by $K\cdot M^{d-1}$, where $K$ is a constant depending on $d$. Think: a shell of thickness $1$ around a $d$-dimensional sphere of radius $M$.

It follows easily that the series converges, if $p>d$.

---

This type of thinking (with $d=2$) appears in the construction of doubly periodic meromorphic functions on the complex plane. The derivative of Weierstrass $\wp$-function with poles at points determined by a lattice is done as such a summation with $p=3$. The summation is (more naturally) over $\Bbb{Z}^2$ rather than $\Bbb{N}^2$. It follows that the double sum will converge absolutely and uniformly in any compact set allowing us to conclude both meromorphicity and double periodicity.

Comment: Instead of spherical cells it may be more convincing to group terms according to $\max \{n_i\}$. The norms of vectors with maximum coordinate $=M$ are bounded from both above and below by a positive constant (depends on $d$) times $M$, and their number is similarly bounded by constant times $M^{d-1}$.